# Drupal CSS Injector in PHP-mode produces error

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-modules

I've got a series of styles to inject (for an iPad fix) on a Drupal 6 site. I'm using the CSS Injector module in PHP-mode. The code to determine whether the styles get displayed is as follows:

```
<?php
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

When I hit save, I get a Drupal error. What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wacky in my code that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What is the error you see? I used the same code and did not receive an error.

Comment: Sadly, the error was simply "An error occurred". I know that's not very helpful, sorry! Anyway, you were able to run this exact code snippet with no error? Maybe Drupal is misbehaving on my end?

Comment: Yea, I was able to add a rule and it ran with no issues.  You might want to check watchdog for the time you saw the error to see what type of error occurred (http://example.com/admin/reports/dblog)

Answer (score 0):

also posting an error report to the issue queue for the module wouldn't hurt http://drupal.org/project/issues/css_injector?categories=All